# Connecting Excel to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm trying to connect excel on a database which has the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Order = [Enter Order]
```

but excel can't seem to find this query. It only shows the actual table and other queries which does not use parameters.

Is there a way to connect excel on a query which uses parameters? I'm using MS-Excel 2007.

Comment: "Parameter queries must be created in Microsoft Query." http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-a-parameter-query-HP005199548.aspx AND http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx. If that does not suit, how much VBA are you willing to use?

Comment: If that does not suit, how much VBA are you willing to use? 
- As long as it works.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Only one problem, the database that I'm using is an Access 2003 database which has a user-level security. It needs a workgroup file to open the database but can't seem to get it working on Microsoft Query.

Comment: I finally got it working. Thanks a lot!!! But if you can show me on how to do this on VBA, I'll appreciate it!!!

Comment: Okay, have fun. You can always fall back on VBA / ADODB if you need to use the parameter queries from Access, rather than MS Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes.

> "Parameter queries must be created in Microsoft Query."

[Customize a parameter query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-a-parameter-query-HP005199548.aspx)
[Use Microsoft Query to retrieve external data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx)

ADODB & VBA

```
''Ref: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim strConn As String

strConn = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
        & "Data Source=z:\docs\test.accdb"

conn.Open strConn

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "Query4"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("EnterText", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
cmd.Parameters("EnterText").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").[A2]

'Execute the Stored Procedure
Set rs = cmd.Execute
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
'Close the connection
conn.Close
```