# End user friendly sql query run inside excel

Tags: sql, oracle11g, odbc, excel-2003

I have an Oracle 11G database and sql developer 3.0.04.  I have a SQL query which collects useful data for users across a system.  The query prompts for two values (using the "&" trick) and then returns a number of columns and rows reflecting their choices.  For example, entering "2" at the location prompt, will use the sql query to pull revelant data for that particular location only.

I can connect to the database using Excel 2003. (ODBC Connect)  I want to store an excel file on the server, that my users can access to run this query - (as sql developer wouldn't be suitable for these users, too complex)

We have Excel 2003 installed.  What do I need to do to let users run the sql query from excel, which will show them the result also in excel?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the problem? You say you can run the query.

Comment: I can connect to the database, I do not know howto run the query from inside excel and view the result.

Comment: You can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815204/connecting-excel-to-access/10815656#10815656

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth...

I'd recommend just turning this query into a *report* in SQL Developer.  There's nothing complex about that for your end-users -- they just click on the report they want to run, and it runs (output looks like a table, and they can export it if/as they choose from there).  Distributing the report simply requires that you store on a share drive or email it to them (then they import it) -- it's a lot easier than it sounds, and also very convenient for distributing updates / additional reports.  With reports, your users won't have to see the SQL, for example (unless they really want to), and the prompts will appear to them as little dialog boxes with plain-english messages (whatever you want them to say).

Anyway, you might find this easier to support / modify / maintain, and I think your users should be happy enough with it (unless they're really grumpy types... :-)