# Issues with outputting results of an Access query into an Excel spreadsheet using vba in Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I am having problems with some code that is supposed to take the results of an Access query and place it in an Excel spreadsheet.  I am trying to do this from an Excel VBA module.  Here is the code I have so far.

```
Sub dbopen()

Dim objAccess As Object
Dim db, qr, wb As String
Dim WSS As Worksheet

Set WSS = ActiveSheet
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

db = "C:\Program Files\BWCApps\Databases\DEP\DEP SQL.mdb"
qr = "Active List of Doctors No Duplicates"
wb = "TEMP UNZIP\DEP List of Doctors " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls"

' Get results of Active List query and put in Excel worksheet
If Not objAccess Is Nothing Then
    With objAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase db
        .docmd.OpenQuery qr
        .docmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, qr, acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\A78853\Desktop\" & wb, True
        .CloseCurrentDatabase
        .Quit
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

The code actually puts the results into the worksheet but then hangs without stopping.  When I force a stop I get the following error message.

"Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)':
Automation error
The remote procedure call failed."

I'm at a complete loss as to what is happening here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815204/connecting-excel-to-access/10815656#10815656

Comment: Thank you Remou. I'll take a look at this and see if I can change it to suit my needs.  Unfortunately, I've hit the point in the day where I feel a bit brain-drained!  I'll post what happens a little later.

Answer (score 0):

See Remou's comment first and see if that helps. If you get completely stuck and decide to start from Access and export to Excel:

Here is some sample code to export a query from Access VBA to Excel:

```
Dim outputFileName As String

       outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\WhereYouWantItExported" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xls"
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "YourQueryName", outputFileName, True

       MsgBox "Data exported to  " & CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\WhereYouWantIt_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"
```

You should be able to add this to an On Click handler or something and export what you need. Of course, this is for Access to Excel, not Excel to Access back to Excel.

In case you needed it, here it is. I realize this doesn't exactly answer your question because the process originates in Access and not Excel.

Comment: Thanks, Newbie, but unfortunately I really need this to work out of Excel.  The transfer does happen, but I just can't figure out why the program hangs the way it does.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: I use Option Explicit as a matter of habit.

Comment: Do you want to try to run, with commenting out .CloseCurrentDatabase   and/or   .Quit  to see if this cures the problem? tkx

Comment: I had not thought about doing that donPablo.  I'll give it a try and see if it works.  In the meantime, I've just created an export from Access to Excel as a workaround, but I'll definitely try your suggestion and see if it works.  Thank you!