# Exporting DAO.RecordSet to XLS File

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm trying to export a `recordset` to a (new) excel file, but getting errors about invalid arguments:

```
dim rs as DAO.Recordset
set rs=db.openrecordset(SELECT * from tblTest where NEW='YES')

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
   TransferType:=acExport, _
   SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExce12Xml, _
   TableName:=rs, _
   HasFieldNames:=True
```

> **Error:** 2498 - An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments.

Comment: You cannot do that, use a saved query as the tablename, reference Excel in the query, or write directly to an Excel instance.

Comment: It is a dynamic query, how do I send a dynamic query to Excel then?

Comment: There are several ways, here is one http://stackoverflow.com/a/10815656/2548